# Why am I getting an 'invalid conversion' error on compile?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07JFD21SW/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) NodeMCU ESP8266 OLED Arduino Wifi Modules which I am trying to load with SpaceHuhn's deauther software from [Github](https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther)

I am trying to compile the source code using Arduino IDE with the display enabled and have followed the instructions to do so from github repository [here](https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther/wiki/Installation#compiling-using-arduino-ide).

I initially downloaded the latest software but as I didn't know which display option to enable before compiling, I went for an earlier version, [v1.6](https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther/releases/tag/v.1.6), which has a video on how you are supposed to install it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elKXLAs3zII).

After uncommenting line 18 from:

`//#define USE_DISPLAY /* <-- uncomment that if you want to use the display */`

so that it reads:

`#define USE_DISPLAY /* <-- uncomment that if you want to use the display */`

and then trying to compile, I get this error:

```
D:\Documents\Innovateking-EU Nodemcu ESP8266\Deauther\esp8266_deauther-v.1.6\esp8266_deauther\esp8266_deauther.ino: In function 'void setup()':

esp8266_deauther:592:32: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]

   display.setFont(Roboto_Mono_8);

In file included from D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\esp8266-oled-ssd1306-master\src/SSD1306Wire.h:34:0,

                 from D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\esp8266-oled-ssd1306-master\src/SSD1306.h:33,

                 from D:\Documents\Innovateking-EU Nodemcu ESP8266\Deauther\esp8266_deauther-v.1.6\esp8266_deauther\esp8266_deauther.ino:28:

    D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\esp8266-oled-ssd1306-master\src/OLEDDisplay.h:243:10: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void OLEDDisplay::setFont(const uint8_t*)' [-fpermissive]

     void setFont(const uint8_t *fontData);

Multiple libraries were found for "SSD1306.h"
 Used: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\esp8266-oled-ssd1306-master
 Not used: C:\Users\cos\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\deauther\hardware\esp8266\2.0.0-deauther\libraries\esp8266-oled-ssd1306-4.0.0
exit status 1
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
```

The youtube video shows the process working, assuming nothing was edited out....  As far as I can see I have done everything the same.

Has anyone had any experience of loading this on to these boards?  Or know what the problem is?

Comment: It looks like the font data being used in that code (I haven't found where that is yet) isn't the right data type.  Probably a conflict between old code and new libraries.  You want to get the newest code working with the newest libraries.

Comment: esp8266 core in 2.5.1 changed `char` to unsigned as default, so it looks like you use some older version of the core

Comment: So what is the best course to fix this?  Use an earlier version of esp8266-oled-ssd1306-master. I cannot use a later version of deauther as there doesn't appear to be an option for a oled display...I can compile it but the display does not work!!

Answer (score 1):

go in the data.h TAB

find : `const char Roboto_Mono_8[] PROGMEM = {`

and replace with : `const uint8_t Roboto_Mono_8[] PROGMEM = {`

Voilà